# Use GitLab env variable in terraform file

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-template-file

I have a secret stored as an env variable in GitLab : `TF_VAR_DD_API_KEY`

In my `main.tf` I am doing something like this:

```
{
  "name": "datadog-agent",
  "image": "datadog/agent:latest",
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "DD_API_KEY",
      "value": "${var.DD_API_KEY}"
    }
  ]
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. How can I get the value from the GitLab `TF_DD_API_KEY` variable and use it in my `main.tf` ?

Thank you

Comment: first observation. It can be a typo from your side when you typed the question as well but you are missing `VAR` when you are trying to reference `TF_DD_API_KEY`

Comment: @JBone with Terraform it will use environment variables prefixed with `TF_VAR_`. So to populate the `DD_API_KEY` variable you would set `TF_VAR_DD_API_KEY` as the OP has done.

Comment: Does the code error at all? Or just not do what you expect. Can you please edit the question to include a [mcve] if possible and also include either any errors or the output vs what you want it to be?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, yes. but if you look at OPs last line, he missed `VAR` after `TF` in `TF_DD_API_KEY` .. this is what I was trying to highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a module input variable like this:

```
variable DD_API_KEY {
  type = string
}
```

The TF_VAR_ prefix will be removed by terraform.

Once you have the input variable your reference `var.DD_API_KEY` will work as expected.

Comment: Not defining the variable would lead to an error that the OP hasn't mentioned. This _could_ be the answer but it's hard to tell from the existing question. It also means that the question and answer combo is less useful for someone else who might have encountered the same issue. Also your syntax is missing quotes so it's not quite valid.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR quotes are not required. This is valid syntax I have been using since v0.12

Comment: Huh, TIL. I was also surprised to see that `terraform fmt` doesn't add the quotes. Any particular reason you use that syntax other than the tiny amount of terseness?

Comment: Less characters the better. The VS Code terraform extension syntax highlighting makes it look odd with quotes too.