How to pass dynamic values to a module's 'source'
I am looking for options to specify the reusable aws modules which are stored in a separate project in gitlab. For example, if there is a generic ec2 component I will call that in my module and pass any specific variables etc.,
module "terraform_tags" {
  source = "git::https://gitlab.my.company.com/aws-ec2.git"
}

The approach works if i explicitly add username and token in the source:
i.e., source = "git::https://username:<tokenvalue>@gitlab.my.company.com/aws-ec2.git"

But I would like to have the code for this module written in such a way that token value is passed as a variable instead of being explicitly mentioned in the code itself. If I try to add it as a gitlab variable it gives an error saying 'value must be known'.
Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

This is not a terraform or a terraform-provider-aws issue ... best you contact gitlab for assistance

"If I try to add it as a gitlab variable it gives an error saying 'value must be known'." Show you are trying that in the question then. You would have to replace that variable in the Terraform code with the variable's value somehow, before running Terraform. Terraform isn't going to use your GitLab environment variables automatically.

@MarkB, there seem to be a way to pass gitlab var to TF as shown in this link, but looks like it wont work for 'source' though. The issue seem to be that 'source' wont accept variables..whether it is from gitlab or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64563458/use-gitlab-env-variable-in-terraform-file

What you linked is just basic Terraform variable support, it's not GitLab specific. Terraform doesn't support variables in a module source at all. So you would have to do some sort of templating of the Terraform file to create a new file with the value before actually running Terraform.

@HelderSepulveda, if you could suggest how to use variables (even TF variables) in 'source' that would also be fine as I have something to work with.

@MarkB, True, the issue is not gitlab specific. I could successfully 'output' a gitlab env variable value using TF code, but could only do it outside 'source'. I see that you are confirming that there is no way TF allows vars in Source. Thanks for your inputs. The issue I am trying to overcome is to avoid having a file in gitlab repo with the token value visible. Cheers.

variables in source are just not allowed today... https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1439

GitLab must have a way to create private TF modules without the need for a hardcoded user and token in the url, contact them for further assistance ... maybe start here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/terraform_module_registry/

this looks close: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/terraform_module_registry/#from-a-namespace
You can provide authentication tokens (job tokens, personal access tokens, or deploy tokens) for terraform in your ~/.terraformrc or %APPDATA%/terraform.rc file

Hi Helder, thanks for the pointers on TF registry. Although I resolved my issue as mentioned in below comment, I am making a note of this to explore in the coming weeks. Cheers!

The source argument in a module block specifies only the location of the module, and is not the appropriate place to configure credentials used to fetch it.
Because you are installing from a Git repository, you must configure Git itself to have an appropriate username and password for accessing this Git repository. Git has various options for configuring credentials, including some that can integrate with your operating system's "keychain" abstraction, or similar.
If you wish to just statically configure the credentials, rather than fetching them dynamically from another place, you can configure Git to do that.
First, you can tell Git which username to use for this repository by editing your Git configuration file, which is typically at ~/.gitconfig on a Unix operating system. The following entry configures a username to use for your GitLab server:
[credential "https://gitlab.my.company.com"]
    username = example

When you aren't using a separate store to retain your password, Git stores passwords in another separate file, ~/.git-credentials.
This credentials file stores a password to use for each pair of username and URL. If your username were "example" (as above) and your password were "secret" then you'd place the following entry in that file:
https://example:secret@gitlab.my.company.com

With this configuration file entry and credentials entry, Git should send the necessary credentials to your Git server. Terraform installs modules from Git by running a normal git clone command, which will then make use of these settings.
The settings described above are for Git alone and are not directly related to Terraform, so this configuration would also work for any other access to git, including access by the module installation command for other programming languages.

Hi @Martin, I had set git config for my dev VM but not the gitlab runner. I now used  "git config credential.helper store" as part of the pipeline to store the creds (passed token value through CICD variables) in .git-credentials on the runner. For better security, i added a step at the end of the pipeline to delete .git-credentials. This way, the value of token is never present in any file on the repo, and only lives for a few mins on the runner. Thanks for your pointer about git-credentials.
